# Uncheck all check in Custom Adapter to check the position 0

Tags: android, checkbox, adapter

I'm trying to uncheck all check within in Custom Adapter to check the position 0. 
How I can do to uncheck all: holder.chkbox checked = false. Thank you

**I have edited my code. This is the all code of the SpinnerCheckboxAdapter.**

**ADAPTER**

```
public class SpinnerCheckboxAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public static String getSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(String selected) {
    SpinnerCheckboxAdapter.selected = selected;
}

public SpinnerCheckboxAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> items) {

    arraylististItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    arraylististItems.addAll(items);
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arraylististItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row_checkbox, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.texto_spinner_row_checkbox);
        holder.chkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_spinner_row_checkbox);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.tv.setText(arraylististItems.get(position));

    holder.chkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View 
            if(position == 0) {

                //CHECK ALL holder.chkbox
                //holder.chkbox[1].setchecked = false;
                //holder.chkbox[2].setchecked = false;
                ...
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView tv;
    CheckBox chkbox;
}
}
```

Comment: can you please post you adapter code ?

Comment: what is your requirement if 0 position CheckBox check == true then all  item CheckBox value is true and vise verse is it ?

Comment: Please check my ans let me is there any problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public class SpinnerCheckboxAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> data;
    private String selected;

    public String getSelected() {
        selected = "";
        for (HashMap<String,String> row : data){
            if(row.get("isChecked").equals("true")){
                selected+=row.get("title")+",";
            }
        }
        if(selected.length()>1){
            selected = selected.substring(0,selected.length()-1);
        }
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(String selected) {
        String[] selectedArray = selected.split(",");
        for (String value : selectedArray){
            for (HashMap<String,String> row : data){
                if(row.get("title").toString().equals(value)){
                    row.put("isChecked","true");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public SpinnerCheckboxAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> items) {
        this.context = context;
        data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        for (String item : items){
            HashMap<String,String> row = new HashMap<String, String>();
            row.put("title",item);
            row.put("isChecked","false");
            data.add(row);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return data.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return pos;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.spinner_row_checkbox, null);
            holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.texto_spinner_row_checkbox);
            holder.chkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_spinner_row_checkbox);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tv.setText(data.get(position).get("title"));
        holder.chkbox.setChecked(Boolean.parseBoolean(data.get(position).get("isChecked")));
        holder.chkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(position==0 && isChecked){
                    for (HashMap<String,String> row : data){
                        row.put("isChecked",String.valueOf("false"));
                    }
                }else{
                    data.get(position).put("isChecked",String.valueOf(isChecked));
                        int count=0;
                        for (int i=1;i<data.size();i++){
                            if(data.get(i).get("isChecked").equals("true")){
                                count++;
                            }
                        }
                        if(count==data.size()-1){
                            data.get(0).put("isChecked",String.valueOf("false"));
                        }
                    }
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                };
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv;
        CheckBox chkbox;
    }
}
```

Comment: It not works how I want. I need check 0 --> uncheck 1, 2... and check 1, 2, 3... --> uncheck 0

Comment: it does rare things like check and uncheck another checkbox

Comment: It not works again. it does rare things like check and uncheck another checkbox. The checkbox 0 never is check

Comment: explain your problem.

Comment: When checkedchanged, there are several problems: or none is checked, or another is checked, never checkbox 0 is checked...